# 'Clearing orphaned inodes' and state lost on hibernation resume

Tags: 16.04, suspend, power-management, hibernate

I installed a fresh 16.04 LTS. I have been experiencing some problems with Wifi applet display error (after resume from Suspend) and with hibernation resume. I enabled hibernation on menu using the method shown [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-help/power-hibernate.html) . Now hibernation resume is not working intermittently. Sometimes it works fine, other times it displays text on resume that says something about 'clearing orphaned inodes' and the system simply boots up anew, without the prior memory state.

Here's some info:

```
$ sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: LABEL="System Reserved" UUID="50921EE4921ECE7A" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="dda192f8-01"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="Primary Disk" UUID="765E305F5E3019F7" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="dda192f8-02"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="Secondary Disk" UUID="E2D42C6AD42C42E1" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="dda192f8-03"
/dev/sda5: UUID="dbaad068-46da-4637-9c45-5c32c20d3cfe" TYPE="swsuspend" PARTUUID="dda192f8-05"
/dev/sda6: UUID="31385b29-f351-4a10-9dcf-c92efd58334b" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="dda192f8-06"
/dev/sda7: UUID="1f734f56-7328-4029-88a0-fa995426d4d2" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="dda192f8-07"

$ cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume
RESUME=UUID=31385b29-f351-4a10-9dcf-c92efd58334b
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I am surprised nobody suggested this as I have been having this problem for quite some time. The answer it seemed was staring right in my face. Apparently my swap partition was roughly the same size as my memory. Also, I hadn't added the link to my swap partition's UUID in my grub file. After increasing the swap partition size to double that of the memory and adding its UUID in the grub file the hibernation resume is working normally for the past few days. Although, the resume from hibernation takes a tad bit longer but I'm not complaining.

You need to make sure that your swap partition is defined in the following files:

- `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`
- `/etc/default/grub`

**UPDATE**

Using low level interface `uswsusp` as default hibernating mechanism drastically improved my resume time to under a minute !!!

`sudo apt-get install uswsusp`

Create file `/etc/pm/config.d/00sleep_module` and add following line:

- `SLEEP_MODULE="uswsusp"`

Comment: Is it still working?
My swap was 1.5x the size of my physical memory, and it did that sometimes, and did not at others.

Answer (score 0):

I just "fixed" EXACTLY the same problem, and thus will provide my solution here, even if your problem is different.

I first iterated through `by-uuid` issues (as I removed systemd, I thought sysvinit could cause device order to be messed up, as suggested elsewhere, and an uuid reference should have solved the problem. Or so I thought.

It appeared to be good for a week, or even two, then it started again.

After this, I remembered what trouble I had with Gentoo, where I had to explicitly set the `resume=/dev/disk/by-uuid/{}` in grub.cfg, otherwise it did not resume, no matter what. There, it fixed my problem. I even installed dracut to manage my initramfs. It again worked for a while, then it didn't.

Then I tried different stuff like downgrading kernel, installing `bootlogd`, but nothing suggested anything special.

At this point, I started to look for more help. I grasped all the - not quite readable - information [here at kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/power/basic-pm-debugging.txt). I tried this, and that, I not quite remember what I did exactly, but hey.

Again it worked sometimes, then again it didn't.

*Now that's where I actually went paranoid, looking for hidden modules in the kernel and envisaging cold boot attacks, figuring that somebody probably got my BIOS assword, resumes from hibernation, then resets the computer and dumps memory booting from some foreign imaging system. (Please note that all this is absolutely not far-fetched, just - as it turned out - completely unrelated.)*

In this quest - today evening - I managed to find this site:
https://01.org/blogs/rzhang/2015/best-practice-debug-linux-suspend/hibernate-issues. From here, I added the parameters at **2.1 initcall_debug**, **2.3 ignore_loglevel**, and **2.4 dynamic debug** to my grub.cfg as kernel boot parameters.

Then it happened, again.

But now I was more attentive. I noticed that my "orphaned inode" stuff is due to "**Superblock last write time is in the future**". I spent some hours finding out what's wrong back then, some half a year before, again to no avail. I just assumed that it is related to the lack of systemd and my habit of using localtime as hwclock (due to occasional dual-booting with W7), so it must be in the interval of 6-10 minutes (imprecise clock source) to 2 hours maximum (I am in GMT+1 DST).

**Boy, was I wrong.**

It so happened that now, with the ignore_loglevel kernel parameter added, the bootlog contained the EXACT date my clock was at at the boot time, as well as the modification time.

**My clock was actually set to Jun 06, 2013, which is presumably the BIOS release date, or something similar.** That is a three years difference (97010350.488716 seconds according to ntpdate).

As such, I finally figured out that **my CMOS battery is busted**. It might be kinda charged - even that it is not rechargeable -, and when I left the computer on for extended periods, it might have picked up a charge enough to "survive" for 1-2 days - or it was maybe just the temperature, who knows. (This is not my primary computer, so it did went some consecutive days unpowered every other week.)

**tl;dr**:

That said, I either recommend to swap out your CMOS battery, or - if it is a laptop computer or similar -, then

1. *(optional, if you use default install of Xenial 16.04, you do not need this)* install and configure bootlogd, so that you will find your bootlog in /var/log/boot. ***(With systemd, you just run `journalctl -b` to get the bootlog.)***
2. Edit your `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file, and add `initcall_debug ignore_loglevel` at the end of the first line starting with `linux /boot/vmlinuz...` under the first line starting with `menuentry`.
3. **Reboot now.** This is very important, so that you will hibernate with the new settings activated.
4. Hibernate, leave the machine off for a sizable amount of time, like hours at least, then resume.
5. Finally, either run `journalctl -b > /var/log/boot` if you did not remember to have removed something called `systemd` and/or installing something called `upstart`, `openrc`, or `sysvinit`.

**For all these steps you need to be root, so it is advised that you start with a `sudo -s` command after every restart, and install something like Midnight Commander (`apt install mc` or Software Center) at first and use that (`mc`) to work with the configs and logs.**

Now you have a log in `/var/log/boot`, in which you can look for events at boot like the actual cause for "orphaned inodes". If you find the "modification time in the future" trouble, with many hours or more a difference, then you definitely have your CMOS/RTC battery doomed too, and will need to replace it.

Comment: I'm not saying this is not the solution, but the odds of having a broken/empty CMOS battery are rather low.    I would warn against just assuming such exotic problems.

Comment: That is basically why I wrote detailed steps for debugging, not just my problem. It could well be a non-reallocatable bad sector in the swap partition, the mentioned dualboot timezone nosystemd problem - or even the "evil maid attack" hypothesized above.
(Not many other things to think about, though - if it works sometimes.)

Comment: The other thing to watch for, **if you do not use systemd**, that your resume (swap) device may switch over so that kernel will not find the resume image.
If this is the problem, you may use `blkid` to find the UUID of your swap partition then add `resume=UUID=<the uuid here>` to the kernel config file in `grub.cfg`, just as the debug params added above.

Comment: What'd you know. My CMOS battery was dying as the time would reset on each boot of W7 (Ubuntu time wasn't affected though). I have replaced the old battery with a new one. Give me few days to test it out.