# clearing orphaned inode freeze at shutdown

Tags: 16.04, suspend, shutdown, hibernate

One month ago I bought a new Laptop (Schenker) and installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
From the beginning I got the same "problems" as in this question:
['Clearing orphaned inodes' and state lost on hibernation resume](https://askubuntu.com/questions/792142/clearing-orphaned-inodes-and-state-lost-on-hibernation-resume)

Now like since one week after updating Ubuntu, when I want to put my Laptop to sleep, it somehow freezes on login screen and I can't even move the cursor and have to force shutdown with the power button.
Just one day later it started that every time when I want to shutdown it freezes at those `clearing orphaned inode`  messages with the `/dev/sdxx: clean, xx/xx files, xx/xx blocks` message at the bottom and I also have to force shutdown.

syslog shows:

```
Oct 11 11:56:51 usermedia systemd[2970]: Reached target Shutdown.
Oct 11 11:56:51 usermedia systemd[2970]: Starting Exit the Session...
Oct 11 11:56:51 usermedia systemd[2970]: Received SIGRTMIN+24 from PID 12946 (kill).
Oct 11 11:56:51 usermedia systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 108.
Oct 11 11:56:51 usermedia systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of lightdm.
Oct 11 11:57:02 usermedia gnome-session[3537]: conky: statfs64 '/media/Data': Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
Oct 11 11:57:16 usermedia gnome-session[3537]: conky: statfs64 '/media/Data': Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
Oct 11 11:57:28 usermedia wpa_supplicant[2944]: wlp3s0: Failed to initiate sched scan
Oct 11 11:57:30 usermedia gnome-session[3537]: conky: statfs64 '/media/Data': Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
Oct 11 11:57:58 usermedia gnome-session[3537]: message repeated 2 times: [ conky: statfs64 '/media/Data': Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden]
Oct 11 11:58:07 usermedia gnome-session[3537]: (zeitgeist-datahub:5470): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to read the recently used resources file at '/home/user/.local/share/recently-used.xbel', but the parser failed: Failed to open file '/home/user/.local/share/recently-used.xbel': Permission denied.
Oct 11 11:58:12 usermedia gnome-session[3537]: conky: statfs64 '/media/Data': Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
Oct 11 11:58:14 usermedia gnome-session[3537]: gnome-session-binary[3537]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Oct 11 11:58:14 usermedia gnome-session[3537]: gnome-session-binary[3537]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Oct 11 11:58:14 usermedia gnome-session-binary[3537]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Oct 11 11:58:14 usermedia gnome-session-binary[3537]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Oct 11 11:58:14 usermedia gnome-session[3537]: gnome-session-binary[3537]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Oct 11 11:58:14 usermedia gnome-session-binary[3537]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Oct 11 11:58:14 usermedia gnome-session[3537]: gnome-session-binary[3537]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Oct 11 11:58:14 usermedia gnome-session-binary[3537]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Oct 11 11:58:14 usermedia gnome-session[3537]: gnome-session-binary[3537]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Oct 11 11:58:14 usermedia gnome-session-binary[3537]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Oct 11 11:58:14 usermedia gnome-session[3537]: gnome-session-binary[3537]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Oct 11 11:58:14 usermedia gnome-session-binary[3537]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Oct 11 11:58:14 usermedia gnome-session[3537]: Initializing Arronax v0.06...
```

Followed by a big block of `\00\00\00\`'s. After that the start is documented

Comment: Do you get anything in the syslog?